# HowTo : C++ App as a Webservice Provider and Java App as a Webservice Client

Tags: java, c++, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm not good in webservice stuffs. I only tried in my life REST in Java which is so easy to implement.

But, this time, I need to implement SOAP, using WSDL as a language.

Would you please tell me if this is what I should do :

> Having an application in **C/C++**, I must add in it a higher level
>   "layer" which will be **Webservice Provider**. My Java application,
>   which would be deployed in another server, should have **Webservice
>   Consumer** / **Webservice Client** by SOAP, using WSDL as well.

Technically, can you give me some **samples** about what I can do on the both sides (C++ side, Java side) ?

Thank you a lot!

**Edit :**

For the ones who downvote, I would appreciate it if they justify their action in a comment.
Otherwise, I would really appreciate the person who tell me if my guessing is right or wrong..., at least.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've done an Edit for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Axis c++](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/) for the server side. Take a close look at the documentation. 
If you are done with the server side, you can retrieve the wsdl file at the service URL by adding ?wsdl to the request. This wsdl file can then be used to generate a java stub for the client code using for example wsdl4j.

Comment: +1. Finally somebody generous who read my question.